# Why is my explained variance a negative value for regression models?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, random-forest, variance

This is the code I'm using to compare performance metrics of different regression models on my timeseries data (basically I'm trying to predict certain values based off the month & day of the year)

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
def regression_results(y_true, y_pred):
    predictions=y_pred
    test_labels=y_true
    errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
    # Print out the mean absolute error (mae)
    print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2))
    # Calculate mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)
    mape = 100 * (errors / test_labels)
    # Calculate and display accuracy
    accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
    print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')
    # Regression metrics
    explained_variance=metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)
    mean_absolute_error=metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred) 
    mse=metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) 
    mean_squared_log_error=metrics.mean_squared_log_error(y_true, y_pred)
    median_absolute_error=metrics.median_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
    r2=metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
    print('explained_variance: ', round(explained_variance,4))    
    print('mean_squared_log_error: ', round(mean_squared_log_error,4))
    print('r2: ', round(r2,4))
    print('MAE: ', round(mean_absolute_error,4))
    print('MSE: ', round(mse,4))
    print('RMSE: ', round(np.sqrt(mse),4))
```

These are the results I'm getting for randomforestregressor model (and all other regression models display similar results, including the negative explained variance value).

```
Mean Absolute Error: 0.02
Accuracy: 98.41 %.
explained_variance:  -0.4901
mean_squared_log_error:  0.0001
r2:  -0.5035
MAE:  0.0163
MSE:  0.0004
RMSE:  0.0205
```

Does this mean my data is bad?